# How to do a row wise count in Hive

Tags: hiveql

```
h1      h2      h3      h4      h5      h6      h7      h8
U       U       NULL    U       Y       NULL    Y       X
U       NULL    U       U       Y       Y       X       X
U       U       U       NULL    U       NULL    Y       NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
X       V       U       U       Y       NULL    Z       X
Y       X       NULL    X       Y       Z       U
X       NULL    U       NULL    NULL    U       Z       Y
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Above data set is has 8 columns h1,h2,h3......h8. if all the all the column is NULL then the count is 0. if at least one column has value then the count is 1.
like the first row has a count of 6.(do not consider null values).

And here X= boy,v= girl, u= wife, z=husbend, y= head. so, how can we find the count by type(ex. boy or wife or head etc) for every row wise. like how many wife and how many husbend or how many girl are there?

OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE

X(BOY)=8
U(WIFE)=15 ETC....

FROM THE ABOVE DATA SET...HAVE TO COUNT TOTAL NUMBER OF MEMBER PRESENT BY TYPE.

Comment: OUTPUT->  X(BOY)=8
U(WIFE)=15 ETC....

FROM THE ABOVE DATA SET...HAVE TO COUNT TOTAL NUMBER OF MEMBER PRESENT BY TYPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate string, remove everything except 'U' (for wife), calculate lenth then sum all of them. Please see comments in the code:

```
select --get total sum()
      sum( Wife_cnt    ) as Wife_cnt,
      sum( Boy_cnt     ) as Boy_cnt,
      sum( Head_cnt    ) as Head_cnt,
      sum( Girl_cnt    ) as Girl_cnt,
      sum( Husband_cnt ) as Husband_cnt

 from( --remove everything except particular character and count them (length)
 select length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^U]', '')) as Wife_cnt,
        length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^X]', '')) as Boy_cnt,
        length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^Y]', '')) as Head_cnt,
        length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^V]', '')) as Girl_cnt,
        length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^Z]', '')) as Husband_cnt
from( --concatenate the string
  select concat_ws(',',h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8) as row_concatenated
  from table_name
  )s
  )s;
```

Comment: where should i put that sum aggregate function the above code?

Comment: i got the desired output now to sum all the counted result we need to use sum aggregate function. so thats why i asked is the above code where should i use that function that give me the row count and aggregate of the count in a same code

Comment: can u tell me what is the function of Concat_WS() . i know its concating the string but what is use of _WS over here?

Comment: @SaikatRoy concatenation with delimiter. In your case simply concat will work good also

Comment: sir, can we get the same output  using case statement for the above problem

Comment: @SaikatRoy Without concat? Sure, but It will be too long. `case when h1='U' then 1 else 0 end + case  when h2='U' then 1 else 0 end +...the same for all columns as Wife_cnt`  then sum()

Comment: sir,now i just want to find the percentage number of household member. the formula would be like.....individual number/total count *100;    like if U=10 and tatal count is 100 then percentage of household U is 10.   for that i used that code but i am having problem that where should i use that total count code ....thats my code. but its giving me an error

Comment: @SaikatRoy Modify the script accordingly. total count is sum(Wife_cnt   + Boy_cnt   + ... all others) . And individual count is like in current script: sum( Wife_cnt    ). Add group by if necessary and other columns for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use concat_ws to concat all columns, concat_ws of multiple null values will return an empty string. With this you can then get the length of your total columns each row (in your example each cell has only one chracter) using length function, this will return the count of non null columns in each row.

```
SELECT LENGTH(CONCAT_WS('',h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8)) as h9 from your_table;
```